# Wordpress Shortcode not working in WP page text edittor

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I am using the wordpress profilebuilder plugin ...when i place the shortcodes in wordpress content area " [wppb-register] "it doesnot include the code .its only showing the text of shortcode.Anyone can help me in resolving problem ..i shall be greatly thankful.

Comment: include your shortcode fucntions

Comment: Have made all the changes as per the https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/screenshots/

Comment: yes ..Tristup i made

Comment: It does not show registration form...only show [wppb-register] text as it ..instead of form.

Comment: [wppb-login] have you tried it

Comment: I think I understand the problem.

Comment: I also tried [wppb-login] ...but same behaviour

Comment: OK then the issues with the shortcode not with the plugin

Comment: I have face this type of issues with VC plugin.Now see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Theme My Login Plugin instead of WPPB Plugin :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/

Comment: Thanx for the answer.This plugin is working well using page template in which i add do_shortcode() function but it does not work on page default template. where i write [wppb-login] ...instead of displaying form its showing the text that i write in page editor

Comment: With context to my problem I can assist one thing that It might be an issue of the CSS and JS which need to be loaded at the time of default template. Please check the View Source for the page it is not working.

Comment: Thanks to all of you ..finally i have resolved my problem.It display form by calling the "the_content()" function in page.php instead of get_the_content().

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that problem still exists in Profile Builder 3.2.8

For me the solution provided by @sehrish worked:

`add_filter( 'get_the_content', 'wppb_maybe_remove_register_shortcode' );`

Comment: @Marchin I posted this question about 5 years ago now I am the plugin developer. This is not the problem with the plugin it is the problem with the theme template. Actually, the plugin developer hooked all of the shortcode functionality in the "the_content" filter and when a theme developer misses this hook in the page.php template then this filter does not display the required results.

Comment: OK. Finally I reverted the change to 'the_content'. In my case the right solution was to change the author of this particular page to Admin account.

This comment helped me to solve the issue:

/* authors and contributors shouldn't be allowed to create pages with the register shortcode in them */